# Unable to Login Using Facebook SDK IOS Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, facebook, fbsdkloginkit

I am following 
[This](http://www.theappguruz.com/blog/facebook-integration-using-swift)
tutorial but i am stuck at a point. after following all the steps mentioned  when i click the login button i get this error i have also attached image of my Plist
i searched for the answer and most of the solutions are talking about url in the BAsic Settings of my app. but i do not get it because i do not want to redirect to any url i just want to load the user name  image of the user as per tutorial.

After achiving this i want to fetch user's information like its email address, date of birth etc

thanks in advance

[image]
[image]

Comment: thanks it helped atleaset now i am not getting any error but the user  name and profile picture is still not appearing any guidence ? i ma runnnig the demo project downloaded from the tutorial i was following link is provided in question thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks everyone, everything else was okay but i forgot to add bundle identifier in settings. So I added a plateform "IOS" and gave my budle id there and it worked for me

Answer (score 1):

```
<key>FacebookDisplayName</key>
<string>Appname</string>
```

not "Appname" ... not use double quotes in Appname

Comment: Thanks every one its working now but i  want something more as well after logging in using facebook i am fetching user name, Email and Profile picture what else can we get and how ? and after loggin in i want to move to next view controller without having that logout button at top guide me about this as well please thanks

Answer (score 0):

Insert [this](https://developers.facebook.com/quickstarts) in plist.info
like this

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
  <dict>
  <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
  <array>
    <string>fb1111</string>
  </array>
  </dict>
</array>
<key>FacebookAppID</key>
<string>1111</string>
<key>FacebookDisplayName</key>
<string>Integration with swift</string>

<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
  <string>fbapi</string>
  <string>fb-messenger-api</string>
  <string>fbauth2</string>
  <string>fbshareextension</string>
</array>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you make you application live ?

Please check linked image for the same
Please delete previous build and check new build for reflection.It works for me

.[image: App make live at developer end]

Comment: actually i added a plateform "IOS" and gave my budle id there and it worked

Comment: Selecting Platform and adding Bundle Id is must for every (FB + Google plus) login

If you change your bundle Id then it is not not working ...and Good to here that your problem is resolved .